# What is the difference between $\arg\max$ and $\max$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What is the exact difference between $\arg\max$ and $\max$ of a function?

Is it right to say the following?

> $\arg\max f(x)$ is nothing but the value of $x$ for which the value of the function is maximal. And $\max f(x)$ means value of $f(x)$ for which it is maximum.

More precisely,

> $\arg \max$ returns a value from the domain of the function and $\max$ returns from the range of the function?

Comment: $arg max - max=arg$ so the difference is the argument.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yes, you are right. $\max f(x)$ is the maximum value  (if it exists) of $f(x)$ as $x$ varies through some domain, while $\arg\max f(x)$ is the value of $x$ at which this maximum is attained.

However, there could be more than one $x$ value which gives rise to the maximum $f(x)$, in which case $\arg\max f(x)$ would be this set of values of $x$ instead.

Comment: I feel like allowing $\arg\max f(x)$ to be either $\in \mathbb{R}$ or $\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is a very troublesome definition. Or using Haskell type signatures, that's like saying `argmax :: (a -> b) -> (Either b (Set b))`. Now we can't easily compose `argmax` with functions `g :: b -> c` or set functions `g' :: (Set b) -> c'`. Unless you clearly restrict the signature to only one of them, e.g. `argmax :: (a -> b) -> (Set b)`... but now the notation must be defined by each author for each unique situation.

Comment: (Assume `b` is a concrete type, and not polymorphic in the comment above.)

Answer (score 55):

Suppose $f(x) = 100 - (x-6)^2$.

Then $\max\limits_x f(x) = 100$ and $\operatorname*{argmax}\limits_x f(x) = 6$.

Answer (score 17):

$\arg \max_x f(x) = f^{-1} \{ \max_x f(x) \}$.

For example, $\max_x \cos x = 1$, $\arg \max_x \cos x = \{ n 2 \pi\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. $\arg\max f(x)$ is the function ***argument*** $x$ at which the maximum of $f$ occurs, and $\max f(x)$ is the ***maximum*** value of $f$. Hence $\max f(x)=f\left(\arg\max f(x)\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

$max$ of a set of numbers will give you the maximum number in that set

$argmax$ will give you the index at which that maximum occurs

$max(1,5,2,0) = 5$

$argmax(1,5,2,0) = 2$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).